# RSA encrypt/decrypt with phpseclib and Cryptico

Tags: javascript, php, phpseclib, cryptico

I'm desperately searching for a way to encrypt/decrypt data between javascript using [Cryptico](https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico) and decrypt/encrypt using phpseclib.